# Are 32bit libraries not supported on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gcc, operating-system, development-environment, binutils, lib

I'm working on the development of a bare bones OS.

While installing gcc & binutils, getting an error:

> 32-bit libraries are missing

Some articles say that 32-bit libraries are not supported from 16.04 onwards.

If it is not supported, which is the best way to proceed with 32 bit OS development?

Will development in virtual box, helpful while developing drivers in OS?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

the best method is it to install virtualBox or VM Ware player and install a 32-bit Ubuntu in it.

If you still want to use it in your current system then the method to install 32-bit should be to add the architecture, update and it then should have imported the 32-bit packagea,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```